# ImportError while using Pylinter in Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext3, importerror, pylint

I'm using MacOS. After:

- Installing pylint using `pip install pylint`
- Installing Pylinter in Sublime Text 3 using package control

…it turned out that pylint was not found:

```
Fatal pylint error:
ImportError: No module named pylint
```

The solution for that problem was to simply add the path to `lint.py` into the Preferences file for Pylinter, which I found to be:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint/lint.py
```

Now, the problem is instead the following:

```
Fatal pylint error:
ImportError: No module named astroid
```

This package is already installed. Any ideas what might be missing? Thank you.

Comment: Did you install `astroid` in a virtualenv? And what about `pylint`?

Comment: @Railslide I did not, for both modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a lot of trouble with pylinter too. The same error as you had was one among others. I changed the location path like described above, but I got other problems afterwards. For this reason, I decided to switch to [SublimeLinter](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/). I have to say, this solution saved me a lot of time and is very satisfying. Furthermore, you have a great documentation and a lot of users, which is also helpful.

Maybe you could consider switching to SublimeLinter to?

Sorry for not answering your question directly...

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. As my pylint installation was integrated with anaconda, I needed to tell sublimeText where to find it. I did it by adding the path to `lint.py`. Then the same `ImportError: No module named astroid` error popped up.

I then told sublimeText where my python installation was and it solved the problem. I dit it by changinging `python_bin` value in the preference file (Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Package Settings -> Pylinter -> Settings - Default):

```
"python_bin": "/Users/HelloWorld/anaconda3/lib/python3.5",
```

Maybe if you change it to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` it will work?

Comment: Good call, but I have already changed that variable to just that. Still doesn't work. :(